# importing and inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, import

Please, help me to find a way how to resolve my problem. I have file structure like this

```
/j/
    lib/
         __init__.py
         ftpserver.py
    utils/
         __init__.py
         mogno.py
         My.py 
         __init__.py
         jftpd.py
```

in `ftpserver.py` I have a class which is the base class for some class in `My.py`
I mean:

```
# ftpserver.py
class foo()
  ...
```

and `My.py` is something like this:

```
# My.py
class bar(foo)
 ...
```

what I want is to use all my modules in jftpd.py. But I cannot find a way to accomplish this. I am doing something like this:

```
# jftpd.py
import lib.ftpserver
import utils.My


***some usage of my classes***
```

And interpreter return me

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

It could be a good solutions to use relative import in My.py:

```
from ..lib.ftpserver import foo
```

but this also is not working method because of relative import, which is not allowed in python. In spite of numerous examples of relative import i have found, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

executing something like:

```
from ..lib.ftpserver import *
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: this should definitely work. can you tell us how do you import foo in My.py? also, is jftpd.py your "main" and is /j/ your working directory when you run the main script?

Comment: yes /j/ is my working directory, when I run script. But I dont import foo from My.py, because it is not possible in python to do relative import, as I wrote earlier. 
"main" can be absolutely empty or have only one print statement - it doesn't matter

Comment: PEP 328 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) recommand no more than level for packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `from lib.ftpserver import foo`. I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work. There's no need for the `..` element.

Make sure you import your original class where you define your inhereted one. For example:

```
from lib.ftpserver import foo

class AnyClasss(foo):
    foo
```

Comment: if it was so simple I would never ask. A tried a lot of various combinations, but that is all, a have implementing your suggestion:
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

Comment: It is that simple. I just tried this on my machine and it works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe I was ambiguous. Once again. A am running jftpd.py. There I am making all imports. You try to build what you have posted in jftpd. I mean you define class bar in jftpd.
BUT my class bar ought to be in My.py in folder utils. And there is no capability to import foo from there the way you posted

Comment: You weren't ambiguous. Importing in My.py the way I have suggested works perfectly. This might be a silly question but are you sure you're spelling the module and class names correctly and consistently everywhere you use them?

Comment: Maybe your editing the wrong file or some silly mistake like that. It happens.

Comment: YYYYYYYEEESSSS.... I am hardly sorry.... As you sad - silly mistake. I tried the way you described and get it absolutely working! 
Thank you very much!
Sorry, once again!

Comment: No need to be sorry, we all make mistakes. Glad to have helped.